# How to get just the command's filename instead of the full path in the "Command" field of glances?

Tags: linux, command-line, top, glances

`glances` show the full path and all arguments of the command of each process in the `Command` column, something like this:

```
520M  51.6M  14136 user            0:46 1     0 R    0 0    /usr/share/miniconda3/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/glances
```

Is it possible to modify its settings to only show the filename of the command instead of the full path and all arguments:

```
520M  51.6M  14136 user            0:46 1     0 R    0 0    python3.7
```